# jQuery drag and drop extend item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an html table in which you can drag and drop items from cell to cell. I managed to find some related code and modified this example and this is the result:

HTML:

```
<table id="#our_table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="event" id="item1" draggable="true">Item 1</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="event" id="item2" draggable="true">Item 2</span>
            <span class="event" id="item3" draggable="true">Item 3</span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table th, table td {
    width: 200px;
    height:70px;
    padding: 5px;
}
table span {
    display:block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.event').on("dragstart", function(event) {
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.type === 'drop') {
            var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));

            de = $('#' + data).detach();
            if (event.originalEvent.target.tagName === "SPAN") {
                de.insertBefore($(event.originalEvent.target));
            } else {
                de.appendTo($(this));
            }
        };
    });
})
```

[**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gL88q17m/1/)

1. What I need to add is: extend span items horizontally over multiple cells on the html table row with drag and drop.
2. Click and hold the right edge of the span item and extend it over two or more cells in a row.

How can I do this?

Comment: Those are two pretty disruptive (to the table structure) requirements there.  You are going to have to change the table.  I would suggest you consider changing to a set of `div` and `span` elements and adjust the CSS.  This is NOT standard drag/drop which moves elements to a new container.